# Excel VBA Code to Force a certain zoom level

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Validated Dropdown list in Excel that is unreadable if zoom is less than 100. I checked on the internet and fvound that I can not alter the size of the Validated list text size so I want to enforce a set zoom of 100.

I have the code to do this as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
End Sub
```

This works and is fine for people who use zoom less than 100, but if people use a greater than 100 zoom it restricts the zoom to 100. Is there a way to overcome this, something along the lines of an If-Else statement.

If zoom less than 100 then zoom = 100
else if zoom greater than 100 do nothing

Thanks.

Comment: You answered your own question: "If zoom less than 100 then zoom = 100" `If ActiveWindow.Zoom < 100 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100`

Comment: I have answered it for the part if it is less than 100 to increase the zoom to 100, where I am stuck is if a user sets zoom to 110 for example the zoom will go to 100 once a cell is clicked. I don't want this to happen, if the view is 110 then it should stay at that level. This is not the case with the code the way it is at present.

Comment: `If ActiveWindow.Zoom < 100 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100` implies "else do nothing".

Comment: Yet when I set the zoom at 115 and click on a cell the zoom automatically gets changed to 100.

Comment: My bad I was going on the code that I had above in the question. However when I altered the code to that provided by @Steven it worked the way I wanted it to. So thank you Steven and Jean-François Corbett.

Comment: Wouldn't you want it go back to the prior setting (say 90) when the user left the data validation cell?

Comment: Not at present. Although the requirements of the list are changing almost on an hourly basis. Readability of the list was a common problem though. I am surprised that Microsoft haven't made the font size of Validated Lists editable in general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
If (ActiveWindow.Zoom < 100) Then

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

End If
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner that will do the same thing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = Application.Max(ActiveWindow.Zoom, 100)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To address returning to the default previous zoom level (and prevent unnecessary zoom flickering I suggest:

```
'Assumed default zoom level= 70
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Temp As Byte
Temp = 0
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3:H9999")) Is Nothing Then
             If ActiveWindow.Zoom <= 70 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
             Temp = 1
        End If
        
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E9999")) Is Nothing Then
                If ActiveWindow.Zoom <=70 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
               Temp = 1
        End If
        
       If Temp = 0 And ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 Then ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
End Sub
```